# Which science fiction TV show was the first to be adapted to the big screen?

Tags: movie, tv, history-of

What was the first science fiction motion picture to be released in theatres, adapted from an original television program? I'm looking for an answer that wasn't a comic strip first, or a radio serial turned TV show.

For example: *Flash Gordon* was based on a comic strip and *The War of the Worlds* was a radio show before it was a TV movie or a Hollywood film, so neither could qualify as the correct answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looking through [this Wikipedia category](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Films_based_on_television_series), the oldest movie I see that fits the bill is *[The Quatermass Xperiment](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049646/)* (released in 1955, based on the 1953 BBC serial *[The Quatermass Experiment](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0045436/)*). The Wikipedia article for the TV show claims it was

> the first science-fiction production to be written especially for an adult television audience

though its cite for that seems to have link-rotted away. This suggests that you're going to have trouble finding anything much older.

If you want a movie based on a show of indefinite length rather than a miniseries, the oldest I can find is *[Dr. Who and the Daleks](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059126/)* (1965).

Comment: Was the theatrical release something new based on the TV serial? Or was it simply the TV serial edited into a movie? (I know the Dr. Who movies were completely separate productions, rather than TV episodes edited together seamlessly).

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with it to comment on how different it was from the serial, but it's definitely not just an edited version: if you check IMDB, you'll see that they have totally different casts.

Comment: That answers my question - thanks!

Comment: @RDFozz: I'm familiar with Quatermass, the movie was a completely different story, using the familiar characters - but different actors - from the TV show.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's probably earlier, but this is the oldest that comes to mind for me:  [*Star Trek: The Motion Picture*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Motion_Picture).  *Star Trek* the TV series aired from 1966 through 1969, and the (first) movie was released December 7, 1979.

Answer (score 1):

Buck Rogers was a live action TV series that ran on ABC in 1950-51. Buck Rogers in he 25th Century was released in the theaters March 1979 first before the TV series aired on TV.

Comment: Buck Rogers was a comic strip first, beginning 1929.